# USPS - How do I get international shipping rates via the API?

Tags: xml, usps

I am trying to get international shipping rate quotes via the USPS API at http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll I have a username and account number and can use the API successfully for domestic rate quotes. I can't find the info for international rate quotes though.

The USPS site seems to go nowhere and certainly isn't helping find what I need.

Here is a link the the USPS development Guide PDF. I do not see anything about international shipping.  https://www.usps.com/webtools/_pdf/Development-Guide-v3-1.pdf

Do you where I can the info about getting USPS international shipping rate quotes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are various API's I think. Looking at the [Ecommerce API Technical Guides Website for USPS.COM](https://www.usps.com/business/webtools-technical-guides.htm?). I see this [Rate Calulator techinical guide](https://www.usps.com/webtools/htm/Rate-Calculators-v1-3.htm):

The call is of the type :

```
http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=InitRateV2&XML= ...
```

And there are specs and sample calls there.

this is a sample request:

```
<IntlRateV2Request USERID="xxx">
  <Package ID="1ST">
    <Pounds>15</Pounds>
    <Ounces>0</Ounces> 
    <Machinable>True</Machinable> 
    <MailType>Package</MailType>
    <GXG>
          <POBoxFlag>Y</POBoxFlag>
          <GiftFlag>Y</GiftFlag>
    </GXG>
    <ValueOfContents>200</ValueOfContents>
    <Country>Canada</Country>
    <Container>RECTANGULAR</Container>
    <Size>LARGE</Size>
    <Width>10</Width>
    <Length>15</Length>
    <Height>10</Height>
    <Girth>0</Girth>
    <CommercialFlag>N</CommercialFlag>
  </Package>
  <Package ID="2ND">
    <Pounds>0</Pounds>
    <Ounces>3</Ounces>
    <MailType>Envelope</MailType>
    <ValueOfContents>750</ValueOfContents>
    <Country>Algeria</Country>
    <Container></Container>
    <Size>REGULAR</Size>
    <Width></Width>
    <Length></Length>
    <Height></Height>
    <Girth></Girth>
    <CommercialFlag>N</CommercialFlag> 
  </Package>
</IntlRateV2Request>
```

A sample response is quite large and is in the docs, but look something like

```
<IntlRateV2Response>
   <Package ID="1ST">
    <Prohibitions>An issue of a publication <!--2143 suppressed-->.</Prohibitions>  
    <Restrictions>Coins; banknotes; curren<!--1558 suppressed--> </Restrictions>  
    <Observations>1. Banknotes valued at <!--3059 suppressed-->.</Observations>  
    <CustomsForms>First-Class Mail Intern <!--358 suppressed-->)</CustomsForms>  
    <ExpressMail>Country Code: CA Recipro<!--2036 suppressed--> </ExpressMail>  
    <AreasServed>Please reference Express Mail for Areas Served.</AreasServed>  
    <AdditionalRestrictions>No Additional Restrictions Data found.</AdditionalRestrictions>  
      <Service ID="4">
        <Pounds>15</Pounds>  
      <Ounces>0</Ounces>  
      <Machinable>True</Machinable>  
      <MailType>Package</MailType>  
          <GXG>
        <POBoxFlag>Y</POBoxFlag>          <GiftFlag>Y</GiftFlag>  
      </GXG>
      <Container>RECTANGULAR</Container>  
      <Size>LARGE</Size>  
      <Width>10</Width>  
      <Length>15</Length>  
      <Height>10</Height>  
      <Girth>0</Girth>  
      <Country>CANADA</Country>  
      <Postage>112.50</Postage>  
         <ExtraServices>
            <ExtraService>
          <ServiceID>1</ServiceID>  
          <ServiceName>Insurance</ServiceName>  
          <Available>True</Available>  
          <Price>1.00</Price>  
        </ExtraService>
      </ExtraServices>
      <ValueOfContents>200.00</ValueOfContents>  
      <SvcCommitments>1 - 3 business days</SvcCommitments>  
      <SvcDescription>Global Express Guaranteed&lt;sup&gt;&amp;reg;&lt;/sup&gt; (GXG)**</SvcDescription>  
      <MaxDimensions>Max. length 46", width 35", height 46" and max. length plus girth combined 108"</MaxDimensions>  
      <MaxWeight>70</MaxWeight>  
   </Service> 
</Package>
</IntlRateV2Response>
```

Comment: For the life of me, I couldn't find it.  This is the EXACT correct answer.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Was going to put a lmgtfy link in :-). But actually the interface quite interesting and with detailed specs and APIs. One of the better documented ones I've seen. I wonder what the local NZ post one is like.

Comment: I've gotten too many lmgtfy answers. I generally do a bunch of research before I turn to stackoverflow.com for help. I was able to find exactly what I needed from your answer and I had searched everywhere for an answer.  Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: The rate calculator PDF has been updated, here is the current one, at least until January 2013: https://www.usps.com/webtools/_pdf/Rate-Calculators-v1-5.pdf